# Comprobar si una validación se cumple asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Necesito mandar un alert por medio de un boton si unas validaciones se cumplen, uso el isvalid, sin embargo no funciona , codigo:

// se valida si un checkbox es true,estan validos todos los campos y se envia una alerta

```
if (validar.Checked == true && revThabiente.IsValid
             && revThabienteL.IsValid && revcvv.IsValid && revcvvN.IsValid
             && revnumero.IsValid && revnumeroN.IsValid && revfranquicia.IsValid
             && revfranquiciaL.IsValid && revfecha.IsValid && revFechaI.IsValid && revnombre.IsValid
             && revNombreL.IsValid && revContraseña.IsValid && revconfirmar.IsValid 
             && revconfirmarC.IsValid
             && revTelefono.IsValid && revTelefonoN.IsValid && revCedula.IsValid 
             && revCedulaN.IsValid
             && revDireccion.IsValid && revCorreo.IsValid && revCorreoI.IsValid)

            {
                btnRegistrarse.Attributes["onclick"] = "alert('Registro exitoso')";
            }
```

// si el checkbox esta false,se cumplen algunas validaciones y se envia una alerta

```
else if (validar.Checked == false && revnombre.IsValid
               && revNombreL.IsValid && revContraseña.IsValid && revconfirmar.IsValid 
               && revconfirmarC.IsValid
               && revTelefono.IsValid && revTelefonoN.IsValid && revCedula.IsValid 
               && revCedulaN.IsValid
               && revDireccion.IsValid && revCorreo.IsValid && revCorreoI.IsValid)
            {
                btnRegistrarse.Attributes["onclick"] = "alert('Registro exitoso')";
            }
```

// sino sucede nada de lo anterior manda una alerta

```
 else
            {
                btnRegistrarse.Attributes["onclick"] = "alert('Registro fallido')";
            }
```

problema: siempre me manda la alerta registro exitoso asi no se cumplan las validaciones

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: siempre me manda la alerta registro exitoso asi no se cumplan las validaciones

Comment: y depuraste este codigo de alguna forma? porque asi como esta la pregunta a nosotros se nos va a complicar entender porque alguna validacion no es valida..

Comment: lo depure y al parecer solo reconoce la condicion de validar.checked == true o validar.chekecd == false , mas los .isvalid no los tiene en cuenta, ( un ejemplo: en todos los campos tengo validacion de que no queden en blanco los textbox(funcionan), sin embargo asi yo deje los campos en blanco me sale la alerta registro exitoso)

Comment: cabe aclarar que validar es un checkbox

Comment: entonces tu problema esta en otro lado...

Comment: en donde podria estar?

Comment: en las validaciones... trata de poner un [mcve] en tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte...